# NoClassDefFoundError: Maven intermodule dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, apache-storm

I have my Storm application (maven) project structured as follow:

```
parent-project/
├── pom.xml
├── storm-application/
    └── pom.xml
├── utils/
    └── pom.xml
```

I structured my `pom.xml` files as follow:

- `parent-project:pom.xml`

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <modules>
        <module>utils</module>
        <module>storm-application</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

- `storm-application:pom.xml`

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.project.parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-application</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.project.parent-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> ...storm dependency... </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

- `utils:pom.xml`

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.project.parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        ... some project related dependencies ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>
```

My objective would be to include the sibling module `utils`in `storm-application`.

I need to include the module `utils` directly in the `jar` package of the `storm-application`module.

In fact, if I run the main function directly from IntelliJ it works, because it recognize the project structure, but if I try to deploy the application with Storm I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my/project/parent-project/utils/MyClass
        at my.project.parent-project.storm-application.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.project.parent-project.utils.MyClass
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

I even tried to use the `maven-assembly-plugin` to include all the dependency in the package but I still get the same error.

**Update**

So what I was missing was that the assembly creates a second `jar` on the form `name-version-jar-with-dependencies`.

Plus, the storm dependency should be of `<scope>provided</scope>` otherwise it complains.

Still, I'm wondering if there would be an easier way to achieve this inter-module dependency.

Comment: I think you should define what you find "not easy" if you want something "easier". If it's about packaging and using maven assembly plugin you could use Spring boot which creates an "über jar" for you with minimal effort.

Comment: @Tristan you're right sorry, I meant _cleaner_ way to do that. I found a solution that I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a cleaner way to do so. Instead of using the assembly plugin, I use the shade plugin, so that the fat jar keeps the standard name.

Finally, this is the `storm-application/pom.xml` that, for me, works:

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.project.parent-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-application</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.project.parent-project</groupId>
            <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> ...storm dependency... </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```